# Asp.net MVC core prevent multiple device access on certain pages

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

My whole system allows one user accessing from multiple devices at the same time. However, some certain pages don't allow it. When user access the page from device 1, later he accesses from device 2, the second device needs to access normally. However, the first device should be redirected to another page (user is still logged on both devices).

I'm using ASP.net core identity for managing identity.

After reading, I think I can use SignalR in this case. Whenever user access from device 2, he will send a message to server. Server will push a message to device 1 and device 1 will redirect. However, it doesn't look good because the redirection is made from client (device 1). That means device 1 can easily refuse redirecting by tamper client code on its side.

What's the proper way to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

> When user access the page from device 1, later he accesses from device 2, the second device needs to access normally. However, the first device should be redirected to another page (user is still logged on both devices).

To achieve above requirement, as you mentioned, integrating SignalR functionality into web app is a possible solution.

You can retain information about `UserName - UserConnectionId(s) - PageName`, then can call hub method to check if the connection Id (and current page name) is different with existing connectionId (and page name) within the retained mapping data and push message to specific client based on connection Id to trigger client side redirection.

> it doesn't look good because the redirection is made from client (device 1).

Yes, client user may disable signalR javascript client functionality to prevent the redirection. As a workaround, can double check on server side.

For example, you can store above mapping data `UserName - UserConnectionId(s) - PageName` in some permanent storage, then you can check it inside controller action (or handler method) code logic, if current user disabled javascript client functionality manually and no mapping data of current user added in that storage, you can redirect user to a specific page that shows content like "signalR javascript client functionality is required for this app, please not disable it" instead of showing the page user expect.

Comment: About the double check on server side, I think i don't have a handler method here. At the time device 2 access, device 1 doesn't execute anything that calls to server. The controller action from device 1 should be called even before device 2 connect and it's valid at that time. Client on device 1 can load the page first, disable signalR javascript afterward.